# Warning :Maven integration requires Eclipse be running in JDK

Tags: eclipse, maven

When trying to import a project I am facing a warning message as shown in the screen shot.

[image]

Here is how my eclipse.ini looks like.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms768m
-Xmx1024m
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: do you have JDK and JRE both installed??? like [this](http://postimg.org/image/s7zbuqoa5/)

Comment: Did you also check that your 'Installed JREs' are pointing to JDKs?

Comment: @polypiel: How to check that?

Comment: can you specify Eclipse version you are using. I had issues installing maven on older version of Eclipse.

Comment: Preferences > Java > Installed JRE's > Edit: check that your 'JRE home' is set to the JDK directory (not the JRE one)

Comment: @polypiel: The location for installed JRE is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6` now.

Comment: @tailorBird, so just change it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to `javaw.exe` to use forward slashes:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: Changed and restarted eclipse. But still showing this warning.